# Do I need to set up route table for my laptop to ssh to an instance with public IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Let me first describe my operational steps:

1. I set up a VPC with CIDR 10.20.0.0/16 (and I created and attached to it an IGW, igw-14ed6f75).
2. And then I set up a subnet subnet_A 10.20.1.0/24. This subnet's route table is `10.20.0.0/16 -->local` (**NOTE:** I did not set route of `0.0.0.0/0 --> igw-14ed6f75` in this route table)
3. I started an instance instance_A in subnet_A, and its automatically created public IP is `52.53.245.253`. (BTW, the key pair used for this instance is bastion_box)
4. I wanted to ssh to instance_A by `ssh -i ~/.ssh/bastion_box.pem ec2-user@52.53.245.253`

   - Result/Observation: I **can't** ssh into instance_A
5. Now I added one route `0.0.0.0/0 --> igw-14ed6f75` into the route-table associated with subnet_A, and then I do the ssh operation again `ssh -i ~/.ssh/bastion_box.pem ec2-user@52.53.245.253`

   - Result/Observation: I **can** successfully ssh into instance_A now

Here is my question: why do we need the route of `0.0.0.0/0 --> igw-14ed6f75` to be able to successfully ssh into the instance? I thought this rule is for the instance connect out to Internet, but not for the outside machines to connect in the subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP connections are two-way connections.  The server needs to be able to send traffic to the client (and once the initial handshake is done, the two are indistinguishable).  Without an egress route, the server could not send any packets back to the client to establish the connection.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html (bold added):

> To enable access **to or from** the Internet for instances in a VPC
>   subnet, you must do the following:
>
> - Attach an Internet gateway to your VPC.
> - **Ensure that your subnet's route table points to the Internet gateway.**
> - Ensure that instances in your subnet have public IP addresses or Elastic IP addresses.
> - Ensure that your network access control and security group rules allow the
>     relevant traffic to flow to and from your instance.